# How to add custom header on spring soap client

Tags: java, spring, soap, client, spring-ws

Hi I would like to add header to spring soap client and I have a ClientAppConfig class which is like below;

```
@Configuration
public class ClientAppConfig {

    @Bean
    public Wss4jSecurityInterceptor wss4jSecurityInterceptor() {
        Wss4jSecurityInterceptor interceptor = new Wss4jSecurityInterceptor();
        interceptor.setSecurementActions("Timestamp");
        interceptor.setSecurementUsername("user");
        interceptor.setSecurementPassword("*******");
        return interceptor;
    }

    @Bean
    public Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller() {
        Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller = new Jaxb2Marshaller();
        marshaller.setPackagesToScan("com");

        return marshaller;
    }

    @Bean
    public SomeClient someClient(Jaxb2Marshaller marshaller) {
        SomeClient client = new SomeClient();
        client.setDefaultUri("http://test");
        client.setMarshaller(marshaller);
        client.setUnmarshaller(marshaller);

        return client;
    }
}
```

Example Client:

```
@Component
public class SomeClient extends WebServiceGatewaySupport {

    public SomeResponse someMethod(ArrayOfLong arrayOfLong) {
        SomeRequest request = new SomeRequest();
        request.setsomeId(arrayOfLong);
        SomeResponse response = (SomeResponse) getWebServiceTemplate()
                .marshalSendAndReceive(request, new SoapActionCallback(
                        "http://soapaction"));
        return response;
    }
}
```

And I have wsdl request like this;

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://envelope" xmlns:v1="http://Service">
   <soapenv:Header xmlns:as="http://Schema">
        <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
            <wsse:UsernameToken>
                <wsse:Username>user</wsse:Username>
                <wsse:Password>********</wsse:Password>
            </wsse:UsernameToken>
        </wsse:Security>
        <as:consumerContext xsi:type="as:IntWebAppContextType" xmlns:as="http://Schema" xmlns:xsi="http://XMLSchema-instance">

            <consumerCode>someCode</consumerCode>
        </as:consumerContext>
    </soapenv:Header>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <v1:someReceived xmlns:ns3="http://Service" xmlns:ns2="http://Schema">
         <v1:parameters>
            <!--Optional:-->
            <v1:someId>
               <!--Zero or more repetitions:-->
               <v1:long>111111111</v1:long>
            </v1:someId>
         </v1:parameters>
      </v1:someReceived>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

I have added username and password but I have to add `as:consumerContext` section, I need to get consumerCode for getting response other wise Im getting error. How Can I get consumerCode with spring ws

Comment: did you ever find a way to marshal Security object along with its nested object: UsernameToken ? I need to be able to set SOAPMessage header section with Security object.

Comment: In my case not any Header java file is generating from wsimport  or maven-jaxb2-plugin but in request it is expecting header my header is something like this

Answer (score 1):

If you generate JAVA classes using `wsimport` in windows, as:

```
wsimport -keep -verbose http://compA.com/ws/server?wsdl
```

You will get `ConsumerContext.java` generated which you can populate with valid data, set it in `Header.java` using `setConsumerContext(ConsumerContext obj)` and fire the request.

Similar implementation you can find here - [writing-and-consuming-soap-webservice-with-spring](https://aggarwalarpit.wordpress.com/2016/07/15/writing-and-consuming-soap-webservice-with-spring/) with source code on [GitHub](https://github.com/arpitaggarwal/soap).

Comment: I have generated with org.jvnet.jaxb2.maven2 maven plugin

Comment: It does the same thing what `wsimport` does, you will find `ConsumerContext.java`, populate it and set it as part of `Header`.

Comment: There is only HeaderType class and yes it has as:consumerContext elements how can I include to respoonse or set it globally

Comment: Set it while creating request same as you are setting `Security` attribute if Header.

Comment: I have added security as a bean which return Wss4jSecurityInterceptor what about as:consumerContext section of header is there any return type  which I could write a bean  ?